# Update statement returning single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and I'm stuck with a query.

I have 3 tables employees, departments and salary_paid.
I'm trying to update bonus column in salary_paid table by giving this condition

```
give 10% bonus on total salary to the employees who are not in IT departments.
```

I came up with this query

```
update salary_paid 
set bonus=(select (0.1*total_salary) "Bonus" 
           from salary_paid, departments, employees
           where 
               employees.department_id=departments.department_id and 
               employees.employee_id=salary_paid.employee_id and
               departments.department_name!='IT')
           ;
```

However it returns this error

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I'm completely clueless on this, please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner query `(select (0.1*total_salary) "Bonus" from salary_paid` is returning more than one value and so can't be assigned to bounus column.

Instead try updating using Joins like this

```
   UPDATE 
    (SELECT salary_paid.bonus as oldBonus, 0.1*salary_paid.total_salary as newBounus
     FROM salary_paid
     INNER JOIN employees
     ON salary_paid.employee_id = employees.employee_id
     INNER JOIN departments
     ON departments.department_id = employees.department_id 
     WHERE departments.department_name != 'IT'
    ) t
    SET t.oldBonus= t.newBounus
```

Comment: This query works wonders. Thanks bud. However just out of curiosity, I was trying to execute the same query through normal join with where clause but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM employees e LEFT JOIN salary_paid sp ON e.employee_id = sp.employee_id
            LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
    ) t
SET t.bonus = 0.1 * t.total_salary
WHERE t.department_name != 'IT';
```

You query was updating all the rows in the table with the result of the sub-query. Also, the sub-query was returning more than one rows. When setting a value, the sub-query should always return single row with single column.
In Oracle, these problems are solved by using join, as shown above. This will update the `bonus` column using values from the respective `total_salary` columns. No need to use sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

subquery should always return single row in return. but you are getting here multiple row using select query. so first check your select query.

```
select (0.1*total_salary) "Bonus" from salary_paid, departments, employees
where employees.department_id=departments.department_id and employees.employee_id=salary_paid.employee_id and departments.department_name!='IT'
```

This query should have only one result but u are trying to getting multiple rows.

let's try with putting **LIMIT** in your select query

```
select (0.1*total_salary) "Bonus" from salary_paid, departments, employees
where employees.department_id=departments.department_id and employees.employee_id=salary_paid.employee_id and departments.department_name!='IT' limit 0,1
```

*you need to change your select  query in that way you get single row.*

Comment: Hi, I haven't practically implemented the limit function yet, but isn't it similar to rownum limiting? Also, the query doesnt seem to execute.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update salary_paid a,departments b, employees c set a.bonus=(0.1*a.total_salary) "Bonus" 
where c.department_id=b.department_id and c.employee_id=a.employee_id and b.department_name!='IT';
```

CMIIW

Comment: AFAIK multiple tables can't be used in update statement? Either way apparently this query returns missing SET keyword error

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to update emails in hr user and had a same problem then i came accorose this which worked for me

```
update (select email as oldemail, substr(first_name,1,1)||''||last_name||''||'@gmail.com' as email from employees
inner join departments
on
employees.department_id= departments.department_id
)t
set t.oldemail=t.email
```